# Jquery Serialize - Multiple Same Name Dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

There are two dropdownlist with same name.

in page:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Kargo", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

And in modal dialog popup:

```
<form id="form">
    <fieldset>
        @Html.DropDownList("Kargo", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

When i try to serialize modal bootstrap dialog then serializing dropdownlist value from page. I mean not serializing dropdownlist value from popup.

**I try to serialize dropdownlist value from popup, how can i do it :(**

```
<div class="modal fade"
 id="bootstrapDialog"
 tabindex="-1"
 role="dialog"
 aria-labelledby="myModal-label"
 aria-hidden="true">
```

```
function OpenDialog(gonderimTipi) {

    var url = "/Market/Home/_DialogPartial?gonderimTipi=" + gonderimTipi;

    $.get(url, { "_": $.now() }, function (data) {
        $('#bootstrapDialog').html(data);
        $('#bootstrapDialog').modal('show');
    });
}
```

I serialize from like this:

```
var data = $('#form fieldset input,textarea,select').serialize()

    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "/Market/Home/CreatePartialPost",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why have you given then the same name (which is also creating invalid html)? And `data` will contain the value of the `dropdownlist` that is in the form (and it only needs to be `$('#form').serialize();`

Comment: I used `'#form fieldset input,textarea,select` because there was a problem in ie versions. Actually i need same name for my logic. It overrides from page but i need the from popup.

Comment: Okay, i made different name. But how could i solve it with multiple same name combo? Or is it a bug? Thanks..